# React hook Form know when value is modified

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How can we know form is modified or not in react-hook-form.
Anyone have idea.
I want know if any of the value is changed and update the state edited to true.

After i provide the defaultValue to useForm({defaultValues:values}).
I want to notified when the values is updated or changed from defaultValue.

Answer (score 21):

Use `isDirty` property

```
function YourComponent() {
 const { formState } = useForm();
 const isFormEdited = formState.isDirty;
 ....
```

Here is the [docs reference](https://react-hook-form.com/api#formState)

Comment: Problem is clicking into a field, not changing anything, and then clicking out of it again already sets this to true.

Comment: works fine for me in react native.

Comment: @Adam B: Read [the answer of Jimmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281332/1323473)

Comment: also refer this answer for the complete stuff.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69646490/2033377

Answer (score 10):

Figured out how to accomplished this.
It is important to specify the defaultValues property.

See the isDirty section of formState [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate/):

> Make sure to provide all inputs' defaultValues at the useForm, so hook form can have a single source of truth to compare whether the form is dirty.

And a short example:

```
  const {
    formState: {
      isDirty, 
    },
  } = useForm<ProfileFormInterface>({
    defaultValues: {name: 'John Doe', email: 'jd@johndoe.com'},
  })
```

`isDirty` will now only be true if the name or email changes.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, even using `isDirty` didn't actually help, so I solved it using `dirtyFields` like this:

```
if (Object.keys(dirtyFields).length === 0) {
    // Do something when there are no dirty fields
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35564742)