# react-hook-form: Check for unsaved changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I have a pre-filled form controlled by [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com):

```
const {control, handleSubmit, formState, setValue, reset} = useForm<UserDetailsForm>({
  mode: 'onChange',
  defaultValues,
});
const {errors, isDirty, isValid} = formState;
...
```

Submit button:

```
<Button
  variant="link"
  title="Save Changes"
  onPress={handleSubmit(handleProceed)}
  disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}
/>
```

When going back, I need to check if the form has unsaved changes and show an alert if it does.

How can I check for this? I tried checking `formState` variables but it doesn't seem to contain something similar.

Comment: Is that not the same as `isDirty`?

Comment: No ``isDirty`` is setting to ``true`` after the first edit and not changing after that

Comment: How are you saving changes, and do you inform the hook you've done so when you do?

Comment: No I'm not informing the hook that the values updated, do you know of a method other than the one suggested below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`isDirty`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate#:%7E:text=Description-,isDirty,-boolean) flag to see if the user modifies any form field:

```
const { ..., formState } = useForm(...);
const { isDirty } = formState;
```

`isDirty` is not set to `false` after a submission so if you want to clear it, you need to call `reset`:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  // ...
  // set isDirty to false unless you set keepDirty: true in the option argument
  reset({}, { keepValues: true, keepIsValid: true });
};
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: So this would reset ``isDirty`` to ``false`` after successful submission right? as if the form was just initialized

Comment: Shouldn't this be a default behavior mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes, that's the point of [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset). About why it's not the default, I"m not sure, I was also surprised that the dirty state is not reset after the submission.